# Retorno de um List Da View para o Controller - Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aplicação-web, .net-core, asp.net-core

Possuo uma viewmodel chamada Perfil, nesta viewmodel há uma propriedade List de ItensPerfil e uma string - título.

```
public class PerfilViewModel
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Código")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no mímino {1} caracteres")]
    [DisplayName("Título")]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }       

    public IEnumerable<PerfilItens> ItensPerfil { get; set; }
}
```

Os atributos da classe ItensPerfil são boleanos: visualizar, criar, editar e excluir e mais um, inteiro (id) que indica o Perfil deste ItensPerfil.
Crio minha view desta forma:

```
var viewModel = new PerfilViewModel();
var itens = Bootstrap._listaPerfil;

viewModel.ItensPerfil = itens.Select(x => new PerfilItensViewModel
{
    ItemMenu = x.ItemMenu,
    Criar = x.Criar,
    Visualizar = x.Visualizar,
    Excluir = x.Excluir,
    Editar = x.Editar
});

return View(viewModel);
```

A função Bootstrap._listaPerfil() apenas carrega os itens de perfil que devem ser criados.
A view aparece perfeitamente, através de um for ou foreach consigo gerar para o usuário dos os itens do perfil, ele só precisa inserir um título e marcar ou não, via checkbox, os itens.

```
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Descricao" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Descricao" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Descricao" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ItensPerfil)
        {
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label id="menu" class="control-label">@item.ItemMenu</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@item.Visualizar" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@item.Visualizar" checked="@item.Visualizar" />
                <label asp-for="@item.Editar" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@item.Editar" checked="@item.Editar" />
                <label asp-for="@item.Criar" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@item.Criar" checked="@item.Criar" />
                <label asp-for="@item.Excluir" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@item.Excluir" checked="@item.Excluir" />
            </div>
        }

        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Agora vamos ao problema, quando retorna para a função Create por Post o Perfil vem corretamente, o título aparece certinho, mas os itensPerfil retorna como null.
Alguma solução para isto?

Comment: No método onde você seleciona os dados, você está dando `Include` dos `ItensPerfil`. Poste também o código do método de seleção..

Comment: Coloque o código na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido. Neste caso não se pode utilizar List porque no HTML os IDs nos inputs dentro do loop se repetem e causam o problema, deve-se utilizar vetor.

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar como respondida a pergunta. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

Barbetta, seria isso que vc queria ver?

```
public class Bootstrap
{        
    public static List<PerfilGenerico> _listaPerfil { get; private set; }

    public static void Configuracao(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        SetListaPerfil();

        services.AddScoped<IAmbiente, AmbienteRepositorio>();
        services.AddScoped<IAmbienteApp, AmbienteApp>();

        services.AddScoped<ICidade, CidadeRepositorio>();
        services.AddScoped<ICidadeApp, CidadeApp>();

        services.AddScoped<IEstado, EstadoRepositorio>();
        services.AddScoped<IEstadoApp, EstadoApp>();

        services.AddScoped<IPerfil, PerfilRepositorio>();
        services.AddScoped<IPerfilApp, PerfilApp>();

        services.AddScoped<IPerfilItens, PerfilItensRepositorio>();
        services.AddScoped<IPerfilItensApp, PerfilItensApp>();
    }        

    private static void SetListaPerfil()
    {
        _listaPerfil = new List<PerfilGenerico>
        {
            new PerfilGenerico { Classe = "Ambiente" },
            new PerfilGenerico { Classe = "Cidade" }
        };
    }
}

 public class PerfilGenerico
{
    public string Classe { get; set; }
    public bool Visualizar { get; set; }
    public bool Criar { get; set; }
    public bool Editar { get; set; }
    public bool Excluir { get; set; }
}
```